# Difference between nav vs div.navbar in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[Some of Bootstrap's examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) use `div.navbar` to hold the navigation bar, and other examples (e.g., in the [Components documentation page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)) use `nav.navbar`. What is the difference between these two approaches? And are there guidelines for using one instead of the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both will output same design but using `nav` tag is more semantic in approach. It represents main navigation of your page. using nav tag helps search engine recognize which is your main navigation on the page. there might be other links too but your top menu is the main menu.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Vivek. Are you suggesting it's better always to use `nav.navbar` instead of `div.navbar`?

Comment: Yes. Its the most appropriate tag to use. As you can see in the documentation section over here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
nav tag is used which is semantic.

Answer (score 0):

`Nav` is semantically more correct and is preferred over `Div`. As to some answers I have read, `Div` is often regarded as the last option to use in any element but we often see the opposite.

**MDN Definition `Nav`**

> The HTML `<nav>` element represents a section of a page whose purpose is to provide navigation links, either within the current document or to other documents. Common examples of navigation sections are menus, tables of contents, and indexes.
> Here's the MDN Page Link for [Nav Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

As I searched some more on the internet for `Navbar`, all I can get from that is `Navbar` is specifically for Links and Button Elements. It is used inside `Nav`, as we see it being used in bootstrap docs.