# nav vs. navbar classes in bootstrap, difference?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

i have just started working on bootstrap and web development, today i came across `nav` and `navbar` classes in `bootstrap 4`. Now, what is the difference between them? and when to use which one? 
i have already used nav in one of my pages and it is helpful. I tried to see the difference between the two in their codes, they seem same since both are 'flex'. 
kindly, if someone could explain this; it'll be a big help. thank you.

Comment: Hi Ali! check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329739/difference-between-nav-vs-div-navbar-in-bootstrap that answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between nav vs div.navbar in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329739/difference-between-nav-vs-div-navbar-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know navbar is supposedly to be used as the main navigation of the website and the nav elements for some simpler forms of navigations. however some people here probably know a lot better than me.